# Jittery ThinkPad TrackPoint scrolling in Debian / X / GNOME using Eclipse Mars

Tags: debian, gnome, thinkpad, eclipse

Eclipse scrolling happens with unbearable jitter, whereas other X applications (e.g. Google Chrome) behave more smoothly, what could be the cause? Why would Eclipse be different from other apps?

```
$ lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux testing-updates (sid)
Release:        testing-updates
Codename:       sid

$ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.18.1

$ uname -a
Linux thinkpad 4.5.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.5.1-1 (2016-04-14) x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ Xorg -version
X.Org X Server 1.18.3
Release Date: 2016-04-04

$ cat .eclipseproduct
version=4.5.2
```

I istalled TrackPoint support for "backports" kernels in Jessie or later using these instructions: https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Thinkpad/Trackpoint (namely, I created the recommended `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-thinkpad.conf` file, which allows both vertical and horizontal scrolling)